# How to know when a IntentService is completed?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, service

I have an IntentService that connects to Server and downloads JSON File and inserts it to the Sqlite DB.

I want to know when the IntentService has finished downloading. So, I can read inserted data from sqlite db and show it to the user.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your `IntentService` raise an event on an event bus that your UI layer, if it exists, can respond to:

- [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) ([sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/LocalBroadcastManager))
- [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) ([sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/GreenRobot))
- [Square's Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) ([sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/EventBus/Otto))

In the sample apps that I linked to, the service also handles the case where the UI layer does not exist (e.g., the user pressed BACK to exit the activity), in which case the service raises a `Notification`.

Comment: Or refer a simple example given here: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html. But I would say give **EventBus** a try.